# vue provide inject status change

Tags: vue.js

I want to change the value of message with provide, but it doesn't work in any way, I wonder where am I going wrong?

I looked through the provide inject event but couldn't figure it out.

App.vue

```
<script>
import Child from './Child.vue'
export default {
  components: { Child },
  data(){
    message:false
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      fullMessage: this.message
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <Child />
</template>
```

Child.vue

```
<script>
import GrandChild from './GrandChild.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    GrandChild
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <GrandChild />
</template>
```

GrandChild.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  inject: ['fullMessage'],
  methods:{
    handleStatus(){
      this.fullMessage = !this.fullMessage
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <p>essage to grand child: {{ fullMessage }}</p>
  <button @click="handleStatus">
    Status Change
  </button>
</template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458780/how-to-make-provide-and-inject-reactive-in-vue

Comment: Check out this https://vueframework.com/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#mutating-reactive-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ref or reactive to change provided value:

```js
const { ref, provide, inject } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const fullMessage = ref(false)
    provide('fullMessage', fullMessage)
  }
})
app.component('child', {
  template: `
    <grand-child></grand-child>
  `
})
app.component('grandChild', {
  template: `
    <p>message to grand child: {{ fullMessage }}</p>
    <button @click="handleStatus">
      Status Change
    </button>
  `,
  setup() {
    const fullMessage = inject('fullMessage')
    return {
      fullMessage,
      handleStatus: () => fullMessage.value = !fullMessage.value
    }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child></child>
</div>
```

Comment: it works like this but, doesn't it run as "Options"

Answer (score 0):

To make this work in Options API you need add `app.config.unwrapInjectedRef = true` in `main` if vue version is <3.3 and also provide a computed property using `computed`

```
import {computed} from "vue"
provide(){
  return {
   fullMessage: computed({
     get: () => this.message,
     set: (value) => {this.message = value}
   })
  }
}
```